# Total no. of $10$ digit Telephone no.

Tags: combinatorics

A $10$ Digit telephone no. is formed using the Digit $\left\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\right\}$ such that whose first $3$

Digit- from Left are $347$. Then Total no. of Telephone no. in which at least one $0$

and at-least one $1$ is present.(No repetition.)

Comment: Are other digits other than $0$ and $1$ allowed to be repeated?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

We have seven free digits and need to place a $1$ and a $0$ in them and fill the rest with random digits. Let $A(n,m)$ denote the numer of numbers containing *exactly* $n$ ones and *exactly* $m$ zeros. Then
$$N = \sum_{n=1}^6 \sum_{m=1}^{7-n} A(n,m)$$
Can you figure out a formula for $A(n,m)$ by yourself?